# Can someone explain why lower_bound is working this way?

Tags: c++, c++17, stdvector, lower-bound

lower_bound function of C++ returns a pointer to the first array element that is at least equal to x (the third argument passed to the function). Here is the code which I compiled online using an online compiler for C++.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(1);
    v.push_back(2);
    v.push_back(1);
    v.push_back(2);
    cout<<lower_bound(v.begin(),v.end(),2)-v.begin()<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output I expected was 1 but actual result says 3. Can someone please explain why this is so?

Comment: From the documentation of [`std::lower_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound): "_The range [first, last) must be partitioned with respect to the expression `element < value` or `comp(element, value)`, i.e., all elements for which the expression is `true` must precede all elements for which the expression is `false`. A fully-sorted range meets this criterion._" Your `std::vector` fails this criteria.

Comment: Unrelated, but please also check out [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Answer (score 4):

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound

> The range `[first, last)` must be partitioned with respect to the expression `element < value` or `comp(element, value)`, i.e., all elements for which the expression is true must precede all elements for which the expression is false. A fully-sorted range meets this criterion.

This order:

```
v.push_back(1);
v.push_back(2);
v.push_back(1);
v.push_back(2);
```

does not fulfill that criterion.

Answer (score 4):

> The range [first, last) must be partitioned with respect to the expression element < value or comp(element, value), i.e., all elements for which the expression is true must precede all elements for which the expression is false. A fully-sorted range meets this criterion.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound

Your input does not satisfy this requirement (not sorted), therefore the output is undefined.

Comment: The requirement is not that the array be sorted.  Using the same call of `lower_bound()` as the OP,  a vector with elements `{1, -1, 3, 2}` would correctly give the result expected by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

[std::lower_bound](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/lower_bound/)

```
// lower_bound/upper_bound example
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <algorithm>    // std::lower_bound, std::upper_bound, std::sort
#include <vector>       // std::vector

int main () {
  int myints[] = {10,20,30,30,20,10,10,20};
  std::vector<int> v(myints,myints+8);           // 10 20 30 30 20 10 10 20

  std::sort (v.begin(), v.end());                // 10 10 10 20 20 20 30 30

  std::vector<int>::iterator low,up;
  low=std::lower_bound (v.begin(), v.end(), 20); //          ^
  up= std::upper_bound (v.begin(), v.end(), 20); //                   ^

  std::cout << "lower_bound at position " << (low- v.begin()) << '\n';
  std::cout << "upper_bound at position " << (up - v.begin()) << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

`std::sort (v.begin(), v.end());` is important, the number list has to be in ascend order.